# convert a positive float array to an unsigned short array with rounding in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, rounding

I have a positive float array and would like to convert this array to an unsigned short array with rounding. How can I do that in an efficient way? Here is an example:

```
float floatArr[] = {1.2, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5, 3.2};
unsigned short usArr[5];
// I could do this
std::copy(floatArr, 5, usArr);
```

However, it will only do the casting, since it basically copies the first two bytes. So the result is `usArr[] = {1, 1, 2, 2, 3}`. My question is how can I convert this float array with rounding, instead of casting, to be `usArr[] = {1, 2, 2, 3, 3}`? Thank you and I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can add 0.5 to each value before converting. That will make the rounding work correctly.

Comment: @Baldrick I just thought about that! Yeah, that's the solution. Thank you! Appreciated!

Comment: @JosephJohns - `floor` isn't needed here. Assignment to an integral type does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you want to round to nearest instead of rounding down `std::round` will help you with this. Use `std::transform` to do rounding and copying in one step:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()  
{
    float floatArr[] = {1.2, 1.8, 2.1, 2.5, 3.2};
    unsigned short usArr[5];

    // (1) Using a lambda to choose correct overload:
    std::transform(floatArr, floatArr + 5, usArr, [](float f){ return std::round(f); });

    // (2) Using static cast to enforce that specific overload is called:
    std::transform(floatArr, floatArr + 5, usArr, static_cast<float(*)(float)>(std::round));

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << usArr[i] << ' ';
 }
```

Comment: This is awesome! I never used 'std::transform()' before. It works really well. Thank you!

Comment: That's great. Better than my suggestion in the comment. I still think like a C programmer sometimes... :)

Comment: That type conversion is a bit fishy.

Comment: @Peter It is here to resolve ambiguity in which overloaded function should be chosen. You can wrap it in lambda instead.

Comment: You've resolved the ambiguity in a way that calls a `double (*) (double)` as if it is a `float (*)(float)`.  That gives undefined behaviour.   A lambda would be better.

Comment: @Peter it actually selects `float(float)` overload. But you are right, in other situation in absence of proper overload it can be dangerous. Editing code right now to show safer way and alternatives.